# Creating multiple addresses in database table

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I'm trying to figure out the best layout of my database.

I have two tables, Account and Customer. A customer can belong to an account. Both should be able to have multiple addresses.

How do I distinquish the difference between the account and customer in the address table? Do I need to create an AccountAddress and CustomerAddress table to do this or can I create a single table to handle all addresses?

I haven't added address to my account or customer table yet since I wasn't sure how to handle it.

Here are my tables so far.

Account table:

[image]

Customer table:

[image]

Address table:

[image]

What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: Since your `accountid` and `customerid` might collide, you should then consider a connector table for each to the `address` table: `account_address` with fields `accountid, addressid` and `customer_address` with fields `customerid, addressid`.

Comment: Gotcha, is that better than just creating an address table for each?

Comment: I think so. Address is an address is an address and they are unlikely to have different address attributes between a customer and an account. Furthermore, you may get some record count savings since an account and a customer may share the same address... one address on the address table connected to both customer and account..

Comment: @JNevill awesome ty for the information!

Comment: Aside: At some point you'll want a way to locate _exceptional_ data, e.g. an address that doesn't apply to either an account or a customer.